# LTI filtering for wide-sense stationary process

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution, autocorrelation, stationary, stochastic

Why is it that if $U[n]$ is wide-sense stationary and it is convolved with $h[n]$ to produce $W[n]$, the autocorrelation becomes $R_{WW}[n] = R_{UU}[n]*h[n]*h[-n]$?

---

I know that in general $R_{WW}[n_{1},n_{2}]=R_{UU}[n_{1},n_{2}]*h[n_{1}]*h[n_{2}]$ and that wide-sense stationary means $m_{U}[n] = m_{U}$ along with $R_{UU}[n_{1},n_{2}]=R_{UU}[n_{1}-n_{2},0]$, but I can't get to the above relation from these facts.

Comment: The expression for Rww[n] results from directly applying the definition of autocorrelation to an LTI system. Please give a reference to how you obtained Rxx[n1,n2].

Comment: I went from $R_{WW}[n_{1},n_{2}]=E[W[n_{1}]W[n_{2}]]$ then used linearity of expectation to get that $R_{WW}[n_{1},n_{2}]=R_{UU}[n_{1},n_{2}]*h[n_{1}]*h[n_{2}]$

Comment: You must have a wrong sign somewhere. Check for example [this deduction (pg. 4)](http://www.pitt.edu/~lfch/EE2521/lecture10.pdf). The operations for discrete time and continuous time are very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically just about using the definitions and doing the math:

$$\begin{align}R_{WW}[n]&=E\{W^*[k]W[k+n]\}\\
&=E\left\{\sum_mU^*[k-m]h^*[m]\sum_lU[k+n-l]h[l]\right\}\\
&=\sum_m\sum_lh^*[m]h[l]E\left\{U^*[k-m]U[k+n-l]\right\}\\
&=\sum_m\sum_lh^*[m]h[l]R_{UU}[n+m-l]\\
&=\sum_mh^*[m]\sum_lh[l]R_{UU}[n+m-l]\\
&=\sum_mh^*[m]\left(h\star R_{UU}\right)[n+m]\\
&=\sum_mh^*[-m]\left(h\star R_{UU}\right)[n-m]\\
&=h^*[-n]\star h[n]\star R_{UU}[n]\end{align}$$

where $*$ denotes complex conjugation, and $\star$ denotes convolution.

Comment: too bad they didn't use the convention of lower case for "time-domain" functions leaving the upper case for "frequency-domain".  using whatever notational convention remaining for the Fourier transform they might see that $$ \mathscr{F}\{R_{WW}[n]\} = |H(e^{j\omega})|^2 \mathscr{F}\{R_{UU}[n]\}  $$ where $$ H(e^{j\omega}) = \mathscr{F}\{h[n]\} $$

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: It's an eternal dilemma: in many textbooks random processes have upper case letters to distinguish them from deterministic signals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm actually a bit confused about the starting point. Where does the complex conjugate come from? I know that $R_{WW}[n_{1},n_{2}]=E[W[n_{1}]W[n_{2}]]$, but haven't seen $R_{WW}[n]=E[W^{*}[k]W[k+n]]$

Comment: i like the textbooks that use a boldface non-italics for the random process.  problem is **that** notation can be confused with a vector.

Comment: @Jake: The definition with the complex conjugate is the general definition for complex-valued processes. You can ignore it for real-valued processes.